# How can I avoid "stringly typed" code in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, dictionary

Consider some code like

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN [DECISION-MAKER] = 'COKE' THEN 'GIVE COKE'
    WHEN [DECISION-MAKER] IN ('PEPSI', 'BLOOD') THEN 'GIVE DEATH'
  END AS [EMPLOYEE-ASSIGNMENT],
  CASE [DECISION-MAKER]
    WHEN 'COKE' THEN 'Employee prefers coke. Give coke.'
    WHEN 'PEPSI' THEN 'Employee prefers pepsi. Give death.'
    WHEN 'BLOOD' THEN 'Employee is some sort of vampire. Give death.'
   END AS [ASSIGNMENT-REASON]
FROM
  (
    SELECT *,
    CASE
      WHEN [COMPLEX-LOGIC-1] THEN 'COKE'
      WHEN [COMPLEX-LOGIC-2] THEN 'PEPSI'
      WHEN [COMPLEX-LOGIC-3] THEN 'BLOOD'
    END AS [DECISION-MAKER]
    FROM [WHEREVER]
  )
```

I believe that the technical term for such poor code is "stringly typed". The key issue in the above code is that decisions are being made based on a string output that the developer needs to type and consistently get correct. If anything goes wrong, the language will be incapable of throwing errors. In a traditional language, the workaround would be to construct some sort of dictionary to handle these cases. What is the idiomatic solution in T-SQL? I don't like the idea of making a use-once table, but maybe a temp table would be helpful?

Comment: I tend to leave such items in a generic mapping/dictionary table.   It will offer greater consistency and reduce the number of touchpoints.   In my table, I have close to 200 "groups" and 15,000 rows ranging from Date Patterns and Conversions to Color Codes.    For example, I had a client which introduced a new Risk Rating ... a 6W(atch) which was essentially a 6.5.    They had to identify, modify and validate literally thousands of legacy  reports and procedures while I only add one record to the Risk Rating Group.

Comment: "I don't like the idea of making a use-once table" How many times will the above query be run? If it runs every day (or whatever), then joining to a dictionary table isn't "use-once", but "use in one place". If you are running this once (in an interactive session?), then a table variable seems fine

Comment: @Caleth Probably once a month or so. You're right that the table would only be "used in one place" rather than "used once", but I still don't like the idea of saving a new table that's only used in one place.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I'm confident that the hypothetical dictionary table would only be used in the query that I'm suggesting. It wouldn't be used elsewhere. Are you therefore suggesting the temp table approach?

Comment: I'd agree with John. Having a mapping table makes the most sense. Then if any rows don't fit your categories, throw an error or send an exception report. The mapping table is convenient as it's easy to understand, manage, and update as needed. Will say at my previous company we actually had a special database for staging tables to stage this kind of data, and these kind of mapping tables lived there as well so they wouldn't clutter up our main application databases and everything was all in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about having a "Use in one place" table. If you still worry about it cluttering up your database, you can use a table variable.

```
DECLARE @AssignmentAndReason AS TABLE ( 
    DECISION-MAKER varchar, 
    EMPLOYEE-ASSIGNMENT varchar, 
    ASSIGNMENT-REASON varchar 
);

INSERT INTO @AssignmentAndReason VALUES
    ('COKE', 'GIVE COKE', 'Employee prefers coke. Give coke.'),
    ('PEPSI', 'GIVE DEATH', 'Employee prefers pepsi. Give death.'),
    ('BLOOD', 'GIVE DEATH', 'Employee is some sort of vampire. Give death.');

SELECT [EMPLOYEE-ASSIGNMENT], [ASSIGNMENT-REASON],
FROM [WHEREVER]
JOIN @AssignmentAndReason ON [DECISION-MAKER] = CASE
  WHEN [COMPLEX-LOGIC-1] THEN 'COKE'
  WHEN [COMPLEX-LOGIC-2] THEN 'PEPSI'
  WHEN [COMPLEX-LOGIC-3] THEN 'BLOOD'
END
```

Comment: Are you sure that this syntax is right? T-SQL seems to dislike the comma after 'COKE' in the INSERT INTO but refuses to give a helpful error message.

Comment: @J.Mini oops, too many `()`

Answer (score 0):

[uses "with as(query)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
with firstLogic as
(
   select PersonID, Name, 
   CASE
      WHEN valueDRINK=1 or valueDRINK=2 THEN 'COKE'
      WHEN valueDRINK=3 or valueDRINK=4 THEN 'PEPSI'
      WHEN valueDRINK=5 THEN 'BLOOD'
    END AS [DECISION-MAKER]
   from Persons
   where country='co'
)
select PersonID, Name ,[DECISION-MAKER],
  CASE
    WHEN [DECISION-MAKER] = 'COKE' THEN 'GIVE COKE'
    WHEN [DECISION-MAKER] IN ('PEPSI', 'BLOOD') THEN 'GIVE DEATH'
  END AS [EMPLOYEE-ASSIGNMENT],
  CASE [DECISION-MAKER]
    WHEN 'COKE' THEN 'Employee prefers coke. Give coke.'
    WHEN 'PEPSI' THEN 'Employee prefers pepsi. Give death.'
    WHEN 'BLOOD' THEN 'Employee is some sort of vampire. Give death.'
   END AS [ASSIGNMENT-REASON]
from firstLogic
```

"with" allows you to have different queries and then join them without creating a temporary table

[you can see it in this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c2a6b1d5b1f9b5821b2da90d3e5a3841)

Comment: I'm not sure if I can see what this achieves. All it seems to do is move the subquery from one part of the code to another. This code still relies on the developer correctly typing out the strings in several parts of the code.

Comment: the goal is to decrease complexity without implementing temporary tables

if you don't want to type the value of the variables. already changes the complexity of the solution